# Xamarin Android - where to store Local DB so i can view it

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm currently saving my local sqlite db in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` with this code.

Now i'm trying to copy the Db to my PC so i can watch what's inside it. But i'm not able to see this Folder unless it's rooted.

Where is the best place to save the DB so i can view it every now and then?

Here is my android DB code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]

namespace AppName.Droid
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ILocalDb.Interfaces.ILocalDb
    {
        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename   = "MyDb.db3";
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path             = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
            // Create the connection
            var conn             = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            // Return the database connection
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use external storage option:

```
        var sqliteFilename = "MyDb.db3";
        var extStoragePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        var path = Path.Combine(extStoragePath, "MyNewFolder");
        var filename = Path.Combine(path, sqliteFilename);

        // Create the connection
        var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
        // Return the database connection
        return conn;
```

This way file will be visible via file explorer

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Is this also a good way to do it when im publishing the app? Or should i better change it back to once i will publish the app?

Comment: This is not recommended when publishing app - user can see and modify or delete your app data..